# How to limit the max characters in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input and textarea I want to limit the maximum number of characters to 20 each.How shall I do it. Assistance needed kindly.

```
<form novalidate name="editartistForm">
<div class="col-md-6 field_container">
    <md-input-container class="md-block log_container" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Name</label>
            <input required type="text" name="name" ng-model="edit_artist.name">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 field_container">
    <md-input-container class="md-block log_container" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Short Description</label>
             <textarea type="text" name="description" ng-model="edit_artist.description" rows="5"></textarea>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wm5fqaa/

Comment: just use default maxlength html attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `maxlength` html attribute to restrict the characters. You can also use `ng-maxlength` which will make your form invalid if it exceeds the maximum limit. But `ng-maxlength` will not restrict the user from inputing more characters. This is useful for form validations.

```
<input required type="text" name="name" ng-model="edit_artist.name" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates like these. Answering them disqualifies the (closed) duplicate from being automatically deleted.

Comment: its working only for <input> but not for <textarea>

Comment: It will work for textarea too. I suppose it t will depend on your browser.

Comment: @Cerbrus This may contain answers from native HTML context but this question is pertaining to angularjs and I have provided answers from both perspective.

Comment: @Vivz: Take a look at the duplicate links that are on the question, now. Those already cover everything your answer covers.

Comment: @Cerbrus None of them seem to mention about angular's ng-maxlength

Comment: Which isn't what the OP is asking about. But there's plenty of results about that as well.

Comment: Op is asking from angular's perpective "How to limit the max characters in angularJS? " and I have given him suggestions about ng-maxlength and if you want to close this as a duplicate, I think you should also take this part of the duplicate answer as well and provide reference to ng-maxlength as well.

Comment: maxlength can be edited from a browsers console and user can input more than the restricted number of characters but ng-maxlength being written in javascript will make the form invalid even if you edit from a browsers console.

Comment: @Vivz: Look again. The answer on the _"AngularJS prevent input on textarea when character limit is reached"_ dupe ___explicitly___ states to use `ng-maxlength`.

Comment: @Cerbrus My bad, You are right. :)